# How to increase the ping

Tags: windows, windows-7

So I just didnt find a solution. I need to increase my ping(yes, increase) w/o any packet loss. Just tryed to find something but got nothing.

So maybe somebody knows how can I do this?
An already written program or an article how to do this. I can write on Delphi/C++.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *increase my ping* ?

Comment: Hmm. Okey, imagine that I'm in-game, so I'm checking my ping and getting answer like 20ms. So and I need to increase my ping to 60ms. Do u get it?
But I cant just fill my bandwidth with torrents/etc, cuz that's gonna add some packet loss.

Comment: [How to increase ping time/network connection latency on Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/687831/how-to-increase-ping-time-network-connection-latency-on-windows)

Comment: @AlexK. thanks man, it works